# Set badge for tab bar item embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, badge

I am trying to set a badge value for a tab bar item embedded in a navigation controller from the tabBarController.m (tab bar controller --> navigation bar --> view controller), i used this code but it's not working:

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:eventCountStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to change the badge for the current tab

```
[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"BadgeValue";
```

If you need to change the value for another tab

```
[[super.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"1";
```

If you need to remove the badge use badgeValue as `nil`.

Comment: I want to change the values from another tab but your second code which is similar to mine is not working.